# ¿Se puede decir “hay gente que tenemos que estudiar”?

Tags: verbos, oraciones-impersonales, haber

¿Se podría usar ***Hay*** incluyéndome a mi mismo?

Comment: hay = existe, así que pienso que si.

Comment: @Lambie ¿Cómo puede jamás *hay* ayudar al OP incluírse a sí mismo en su frase?

Answer (score 3):

La frase es un tanto ambigua: depende de si *gente* debe funcionar como sujeto o como objeto directo de *estudiar*.

Si lo que pretendemos decir es que algunas personas, entre ellas yo, tenemos que estudiar, la respuesta es no. Es perfectamente válido decir:

> Hay gente que tiene que estudiar

con el sentido de que algunas personas tienen que estudiar y por eso no pueden ir a una fiesta, o pedimos que se guarde silencio... Pero, si entre esas personas estamos nosotros, debemos recurrir a otra construcción como:

> Algunos tenemos que estudiar

En cambio, si lo que pretendemos es decir que hay gente que debe ser objeto de estudio, la construcción es válida, aunque yo no la aconsejaría porque no queda nada clara. Leyendo esa frase, no creo que a nadie se le ocurriera pensar que yo estoy entre esas personas que deben ser objeto de estudio, a menos que lo aclaremos.

En resumen: si nosotros mismos formamos parte de esa *gente*, es mejor que utilices otra construcción, porque esta es incorrecta o, al menos, confusa.

Answer (score 2):

**Se puede estudiar cualquier asunto o persona o cosa.**

hay=existe.

Para mi, "Hay gente que tenemos que estudiar" se puede comparar con cualquier otra cosa que se estudia.

Así que "Hay gente que tenemos que estudiar" me parece válido.

"Hay personages históricos que tenemos que estudiar.

Verbo tener + que:

17. tr. Denota la necesidad o determinación de hacer aquello que expresa una cláusula posterior introducida por que. Tendré que salir.

[Real Academia Española](https://dle.rae.es/tener)

Answer (score 1):

No, eso no sirve. *Hay* es la conjugación impersonal del verbo *haber*, mientras que *tenemos* es la conjugación en primera persona del plural de *tener*. Es válido el uso de cualquiera de los verbos para emitir juicios morales o éticos. Pero usar *hay* y *tenemos* en una misma oración carece de sentido porque el sujeto *gente* está concordando con *hay* pero no lo está con *tenemos*. Asimismo, en general *hay* y *tenemos* no se llevan muy bien, justamente porque el tipo de sujeto que especifican es diferente.

**Posibles formas de corregirlo**

**Cambiar *tenemos* por *tiene***

> #Hay gente que tiene que estudiar.

Ahora los verbos y el sujeto está en concordancia, pero esto no es lo que querés porque al estar impersonal y en tercera persona te excluye.

**Omitir *hay ... que***

> Algunos tenemos que estudiar

Es lo más simple, en primera persona incluyéndote, tal como querías. Fijate que *tenemos* y *hay* cumplían la misma función en la frase, por lo tanto era redundante que ambos estuvieran. Y **tenemos** es lo que da la sensación de incluirte, mientras que **hay** lo único que hace es distanciarte de la situación.

Comment: Hay libros que tenemos que estudiar. ¿ Porque no gente? hay es existe. No veo ningún problem.

Comment: No sé cual es es sentido. Solo tengo lo que puso la persona. En esto **caso** hay peude ser existe, no siempre, claro. No necesito la RAE para eso. :)